# PyScript unable to open database file but works in Python

Tags: python, html, sqlite, pyscript

Using PyScript in my HTML documents I run into an error:

```
JsException(PythonError: Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 429, 
  in eval_code .run(globals, locals) 
File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 300, 
  in run coroutine = eval(self.code, globals, locals) 
File "", line 3, 
  in sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file )
```

When running the program in Python it works. I gave needed files all permissions (chmod 777) which solved nothing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
      <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
    <style>
    #Ausgabe {
    background-color: red;
    }
   </style>
   <py-env>
   -sqlite3
   </py-env>
  </head>
  <body>
<main>
 <textarea id="Ausgabe"> </textarea>
</main>
<py-script>
import sqlite3
#opening the database 
connecting= "home/marcel/Schreibtisch/Studium/JustForFun/Betrag.db"
connection = sqlite3.connect(connecting)
cursor = connection.cursor()

#executing the connection and printing each row in the db
sql = "SELECT * FROM personen "
cursor.execute(sql)
connection.commit()
for dsatz in cursor:
    ausgab= dsatz[0] + " " + dsatz[1] + " " + dsatz[2]
    pyscript.write("Ausgabe",ausgab)
connection.close()
</py-script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd check `os.path.exists` on the database path from inside that code.

Comment: i tried using it in my script, and id did nothing, even when i did a normal if clause to check if the path exists it didn't even output my else for some reason, i think importing packages might be the issue, but using matplotlib worked, so idk.

Comment: you forgot `/` at the beginning `"/home/marcel/..."` so it may treats it as `relative path` instead of `absolute path` - and it may search file in wrong place.

Comment: is this your real code? `sqlite3` is standard module and it doesn't need to be in `<py-env>`   - and it may even generate error because it may try to download `sqlite3` from server `pypi.org` but this module doesn't exist on this server.

Comment: You may not access local files for security reason - see pyodide [Why can’t I load files from the local file system?](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/faq.html#why-can-t-i-load-files-from-the-local-file-system) You can only use `HTTP` and `urls` to access some files. But `sqlite3` may not know how to use it. you could use url to access file (in some restricted folders) and use `io.StringIO` to simulate local file in memory but other problem can be how to save it back on server. It would need to send file with POST request and server would have to get it and save it.

Comment: @furnas no, this isn't my real code, I just cut it out because this is the part which causes the trouble. I'll try it later but regarding what you send afterwards if have my doubts. However thank you for your help I have to look for another splution then.

Answer (score 2):

Pyscript has the same restrictions that JavaScript has when running in the browser. No local file access, no sockets, nothing that tries to escape out of the browser sandbox.

In your case, you are trying to directly access a sqlite3 database file located on the local file systems. That is not possible in Pyscript or JavaScript running inside a browser.

Comment: Surprised no one’s upvoted this yet.  Standard browser security sandboxing is most certainly applicable here, as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer and it worked for me.

from:[JULIEN'S DATA BLOG](https://www.blanchardjulien.com/posts/sql_pyscript/)

**Files and libraries in PyScript**

One of the main issues I encountered while working with PyScript last year, was how difficult it felt to access either local or remote files. As PyScript creates its own virtual runtime, getting my scripts to interact with the “outside world” turned out to be more challenging than it had initially seemed. So why come back to it now you might ask? Well I recently read that the way the main configuration tags work has drastically improved, making importing libraries easier and allowing users to do some fancy stuff like load local and remote files. Without further ado, let’s see how PyScript’s new  tags now work:

Accessing local files has been made much easier thanks to the [[fetch]] configuration argument:

```
<py-config>
      [[fetch]]
      files = ["./whatever_file_you_want_to_work_with.extension"]
</py-config>
```

Comment: [/help/referencing](/help/referencing)

Comment: You realize that `fetch` is loading `whatever_file_you_want_to_work_with` from the remote web server and does not and cannot load files from the user's local file system. Accessing a local file from a browser application requires using the browser APIs. There is no method around that. If there was, that would be a giant security hole. If you refer to the PyScript [documentation](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/tutorials/py-config-fetch.html) notice the wording `fetch from a remote server`.