# Using files in Pyscript

Tags: javascript, python, html, pyscript

I need to use some files in my Pyscript algorithm, and I know Pyscript can´t access local files because of a security issue. But my question is, can I somehow upload those files to a virtual file system, because otherwise I'm going to be unable to run my script. When using the open() function, I'm getting an error where the file isn't found.

Comment: Do you mean "my Pyscript-based algorithm"? There's ways to provide files to work with pyscript. They are covered in the documentation and a good summary of the situation as of the middle of last year is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76597559/8508004). Have you looked over that? "can I somehow upload those files to a virtual file system"? There's options related to that. You can upload the files to where your html files containing pyscript code are hosted and then the pyscript code can see the files like a web. Or you can use  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76148659/8508004) ...

Comment: <continued>  to fetch the file from a URL. [This example](https://pyscript.com/@examples/panel-and-hvplot/latest) gets the CSV file from github using the latest approaches it seems. I was using the older ways earlier this month and they worked, [see specifically last paragraph here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77952068/8508004). [The other answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77969225/8508004) may help you as well as it is current and worked. My feelings are though that if you are trying to do data exploration with pyodide, ...

Comment: <continued> which is what pyscript uses to run the code, and need to be flexible with what files you access because they change, then you may as well use JupyterLite where there is a familiar user interface where you can simply drag-and-drop the files from your local system into the virtual file system running in your browser. If you make anything useful, like a Jupyter `.ipynb` file, then download it back to your local system's file system because if something goes kablooie with your browser or you clear the cache, ...

Comment: <continued> you lose the files developed within the virtual file system of JupyterLite at this time. In other words, always best to treat the virtual file system as if it is a remote system you don't own and may go away unexpectedly.

Comment: @Wayne Thank you very much for your answer. Im trying to access de MSINT database, and I have the files locally. I could try to get a github URL to fetch, but don't know which one to choose. Im not very experienced in this world, and I'm having trouble understanding some of the concepts. Would it help if I posted the code? I tried inputting your solution using the [[fetch]] function, but now I'm running into an error. Uncaught YAMLException$1 YAMLException$1
    at throwError (//node_modules/js-yaml/dist/js-yaml.mjs:1277:3)

Comment: That error isn't familiar to me. Do you mean [the MNIST Database of Handwritten Digits](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/dataset/683/mnist+database+of+handwritten+digits)? "Im not very experienced in this world". I'm wondering then if maybe picking a way to work that is still actively developing and experimental is not the way to go. Why not use Python and/or Jupyter with a normal Python-based kernel may be an easier way to to go about this? Or did you just mean using the web and pyscript you aren't  familiar with?

Comment: @Wayne I made a python algorithm that uses knn to determine which number is more similar to the number drawn by the user. However, to make it a challenge, I was going to try to combine that algorithm with a website, which makes it easier to make a canvas and draw such number. However, I'm not too comfortable with pyscript, javascript and web itself. I feel confident in my python abilities, (and yes, I meant the MNIST database, sorry for the typo), but Im having trouble with the training part of the algorithm (I have to access those files for training)

Comment: Oh, I see you want to be able to let the user draw. I think you can still add this functionality in Jupyter and it may be easier. See [here](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/3175#issuecomment-809223441). If the training is done separately and so you are not needing a lot of computational power at that point, then you can maybe use mybinder.org service to share your repo with the notebook. You can even make the notebook into an app with [Voila](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila#). [The Voila gallery](https://voila-gallery.org/) has some machine learning-related...

Comment: <continued> examples and all those are **based on Jupyter notebooks** & served via the MyBinder service for free from GitHub repos. [Here is a classifier](https://github.com/Allen-BME/bear-classifier#bear-classifier) that you can run via MyBinder service that has Voila or standard Jupyter option. I seen other people use [HuggingFace](https://huggingface.co/spaces) or Google Colab to share this sort of thing more easily than doing web-based development themselves & using the more limited pyodide kernel. [Here](https://github.com/widgetti/wanderlust) is a HuggingFace one based on Python.

Comment: @Wayne I followed your advice and redid everything in Jupyter Notebook (really grateful for the advice). However, when trying to use Voila to make it into an app, the canvas from ipycanvas I'm using isn't being rendered. Any advice?

Comment: There's a special approach needed for ipycanvas with Voila. Had you seen [here](https://ipycanvas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#ipycanvas-in-voila)?

Comment: @Wayne Yeah i checked the entire documentation and tried exactly that approach (copy and pasted that code for testing purposes) but couldn't get it to work. It still rendered as an empty canvas. Is there anywhere where I can show you my code? Anyways, thank you so much for all that help and advice, you have truly been a lifesaver

Comment: If you are sure you followed the documentation, maybe filing an issue at the ipycanvas github site about that may get you more traction? You can reference your code there.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the files available "to the network" (either on a web server, or served locally with something like `python3 -m http.serve` or another [simple dev server](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/set_up_a_local_testing_server)), you can uses the [[files] key](https://pyscript.github.io/docs/2024.2.1/user-guide/configuration/#files) in py-config to load those files into the virtual filesystem.

The older `[[fetch]]` key is also available, but it's a little error-prone due to its complexity and options, so `[files]` is currently the recommended way forward.

Comment: Also, from another question you recently asked, it looks like you're still using the `alpha` release of pyscript, which has had many releases since then. See the examples at https://pyscript.github.io/docs/2024.2.1/beginning-pyscript/ .

Comment: @Wayne does it work if you link directly to the most recent release (`https://pyscript.net/releases/2024.03.2/core.js` as of today) instead of `/latest`?

Comment: Yes, it works with `https://pyscript.net/releases/2024.3.2/core.js` , which I suspect is what you meant since that other one is not valid. (Now working [here](https://fomightez.github.io/pyscript_test/csv_Mar_2024_files_key_test.html).) Part of the issue is that leaving the plugins directive in `py-config` caused it to fail silently it seemed. I did notice though you mentioned plugins as an issue in [your post about the November overhaul](https://jeff.glass/post/whats-new-pyscript-2023-11-1/) and thought maybe best to try without it.  However, I don't see the interactive terminal working ...

Comment: <continued> as spelled out [here](https://jeff.glass/post/whats-new-pyscript-2023-11-1/) which made figuring out how to get `Element` working again difficult. (I was hoping I could keep trying import statements in an interactive console.) I stumbled through at least importing pydom from pyweb, yet gettting it to toggle visibility of a div didn't seem to work and so I made the div not hidden to get past that small hitch.